# Assign new matrices for a certain condition, in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements, criteria, assign

I have a matrix,DataFile=8x8. One of those columns(column 6 or "coarse event") can only be 0 or a 1. It will be 0 for a non-stable condition and 1 for a stable condition.Now for the example:

```
DataFile = [ 11 5 66 1.2 14.1 0 -1 0.1;...
             12 6 67 1.4 15.1 0 -1 0.1;...
             13 7 68 1.6 16.1 1 -1 0.2;...
             14 8 69 1.7 16.5 1 -2 0.1;...
             15 9 68 1.6 16.2 0 -1 0.3;...
             16 8 66 1.3 15.7 1 -2 0.0;...
             17 5 65 1.5 16.1 1  0 0.0;...
             18 6 66 1.2 16.6 0  1 1.0];
```

With slight changes from the code in the comments:

```
DataFile =[zeros(1,size(DataFile,2)); DataFile; zeros(1,size(DataFile,2))];    
startInd = [find(diff(DataFile(:,6))==1)]; 
endInd   = [find(diff(DataFile(:,6)) <0)];

B={};
for n=1:1:numel(endInd)
    B(n)={DataFile(startInd(n):endInd(n),:)};
end

FirstBlock=B{1};
SecondBlock=B{2};
```

The result is 2 matrices(FirstBlock=3x8,SecondBlock=3x8), which wrongfully includes 0's in the 6th column. It should be giving two matrices(dataIs1(1)=2x8 and dataIs1(2)=2x8), with only 1's in the 6th column.

In reality I would like have the a n-amount of matrices, for which the "coarse event" is 1. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic word is [logical indexing](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1/%22logical%20indexing%22):

If you have a Matrix A:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5;...
   0 6 7 8 9;...
   1 7 8 9 10]
```

you can extact Row 1 and 2 by:

```
B=A(A(:,1)==1)
```

Hope thats waht your looking for, have fun.

To seperate the groups we need to know where they start and end:

```
endInd   = [find(diff(A(:,1))<0) size(A,1)]
startInd = [1 find(diff(A(:,1))==1)]
```

Then assigne the Data to arrays:

```
B={};
for n=1:1:numel(endInd)
    B(n)={A(startInd(n):endInd(n),:)};
end
```

---

Edit: 
Your new Data:

```
DataFile = [ 11 5 66 1.2 14.1 0 -1 0.1;...
         12 6 67 1.4 15.1 0 -1 0.1;...
         13 7 68 1.6 16.1 1 -1 0.2;...
         14 8 69 1.7 16.5 1 -2 0.1;...
         15 9 68 1.6 16.2 0 -1 0.3;...
         16 8 66 1.3 15.7 1 -2 0.0;...
         17 5 65 1.5 16.1 1  0 0.0;...
         18 6 66 1.2 16.6 0  1 1.0];
```

I add some padding to avoid mistakes:

```
DataFile =[zeros(1,size(DataFile,2)); DataFile; zeros(1,size(DataFile,2))]
```

Now, as before, we look for the starts and ends of the blocks:

```
 endInd   = [find(diff(A(:,1)) <0) -1]
 startInd = [find(diff(A(:,1))==1)]
```

Then assigne the Data to a cell in a arrays:

```
B={};
for n=1:1:numel(endInd)
    B(n)={A(startInd(n):endInd(n),:)};
end
```

If you want to retrive, say, the second block:

```
secondBlock=B{2};
```

Comment: Hello. Yes this is close to what I had in mind, but the logical indexing you are using also just makes one matrix for all "coarse event" values that are 1. How would you use a if,while or for statement to create n-amount of matrices(B,C,D,E,etc) for which the "coarse event" is 1.

Comment: Dear Marco Wassmer, thank you for the help! I am very close to achieving the whole purpose.

Comment: Marco, thank you, you have already gone above and beyond the call of duty to help me. I think we are very close now, please assist me again in the last edit in my question. (Let us delete the comments which are not applicable). You should be rewarded with a medal for your help.

Comment: @Div your welcome, small mistake on my side :  `endInd   = [find(diff(A(:,1)) <0)]-1`<= forgot minus 1